# Movie is not a constructor - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using the MEAN stack and trying to save data to my MongoDB database with Mongoose. However, I keep getting the error 
"Movie is not a constructor" for my model. But this is how the Mongoose docs show it, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong..

Please help!

**Movie.js**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    genre: String
});

export let Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", MovieSchema);
```

**route.js**

```
import express = require('express');
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Movie = require('../models/Movie');
let router = express.Router();

router.post('/movies', function(req, res, next) {
  let new_movie = new Movie(req.body);
  new_movie.save(function(err, movie) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.send(movie);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you using typescript or some other transpiler? node.js still doesn't support `import` AFAIK.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same problem. @JohnnyHK, my babel transpiler is working :) Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

This problem happens when you forget to export your model from the model file or exports in a  wrong way. your model should export like this:

```
let Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", MovieSchema);
module.exports=Movie;
```

Or in a shorthand you can simply write:

```
module.exports=mongoose.model('Movie',MovieSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably your issue has resolved but sharing information is always good.

Maybe this will help others :)

You can create your Schema using:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    userName: String,
    points: Number,
    userImage: String
});
```

then you need to use `mongoose.model`

```
const user = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The first argument is the **singular name of the collection** your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, **the model User is for the Users collection in the database**.

The .model() function makes a copy of schema.

**Make sure that you've added everything you want to schema before calling .model()**

For more information you can check: [mongooseSchematypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), [mongooseModels](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Hope it helps ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line in Movie.js file with

```
let Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", MovieSchema);
module.exports=Movie;
```

Answer (score -1):

You're calling constructor `mongoose.Schema` twice, once in `Movie.js`:

`let Movie = new mongoose.Schema({...})`

and the second in `route.js`:

`let new_movie = new Movie(req.body);`

remove `new` keyword in `Movie.js` before `mongoose.Schema`

And maybe change your last line in your `Movie.js` to:

`let Movie = module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);`

Answer (score -2):

In the require path use the entire filename. So Movie.js instead of Movie. Because you're pointing to a file, not a node_module.

```
let Movie = require('../models/Movie.js')
```